# Actualizar estado active en <nav>

Tags: html, html5, navbar, bootstrap-5, dropdown

¿Por qué cuando interactuo con los elementos del dropdown y luego quiero interactuar con los demas elementos no me desmarca las opciones dentro del dropdown, siempre las deja activas y me bloquea el acceso a sus tab-content

```
<nav id="patientoptions">
                                <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">


                                    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-consulta" type="button" 
                                        role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Consulta">
                                        <i class="histonav bi-ui-radios"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-antecedentes" type="button" 
                                        role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Antecedentes">
                                        <i class="histonav bi-shield-lock-fill"></i>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-diagnostico" type="button" 
                                        role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Diagnóstico">
                                        <i class="histonav bi-file-post"></i> 
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="histonav bi-heart-pulse-fill"></i></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <sub class="dropdown-header">Tratamiento</sub>
                                          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-medicamento" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="#nav-medicamento" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-capsule"></i> Médicamentos </a></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-suministros" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="#nav-suministros" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-box-seam-fill"></i> Suministros</a></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-recomendaciones" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="#nav-recomendaciones" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-chat-left-text-fill"></i> Recomendaciones</a></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-Incapacidad" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="#nav-Incapacidad" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-virus"></i> Incapacidad</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>                                        
                                    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-ayudadx" type="button" 
                                        role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Ayuda Dx. Procedimientos y Drogodependencia">
                                        <i class="histonav bi-file-earmark-medical-fill"></i> 
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
```

Comment: Podés agregar un [repro] en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). De hacerlo, no olvides además agregar la librería de bootstrap, con el botón "Añadir librería externa" (a la izquierda de la pantalla, debajo de las opciones).

Comment: Estas preguntas de la clase .active en elementos de un menú se han [repetido demasiadas veces en el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=active+menu). Por favor revisa: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás duplicando atributos `data-bs-toggle` en los **dropdown-item**.

Seguramente querias poner **data-bs-target** en lugar de **data-bs-toggle** en la segunda ocurrencia de cada línea:

Es decir, por ejemplo, cambia esto:

```
data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-toggle="#nav-medicamento"
```

por esto:

```
data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-medicamento"
```

y así en los 4 dropdown-item que tienes.

Ejemplo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<nav id="patientoptions">
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">

    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-consulta" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Consulta">
      <i class="histonav bi-ui-radios"></i>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-antecedentes" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Antecedentes">
      <i class="histonav bi-shield-lock-fill"></i>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-diagnostico" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Diagnóstico">
      <i class="histonav bi-file-post"></i>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="histonav bi-heart-pulse-fill"></i></a>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <sub class="dropdown-header">Tratamiento</sub>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-medicamento" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-medicamento" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-capsule"></i> Médicamentos </a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-suministros" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-suministros" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-box-seam-fill"></i> Suministros</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-recomendaciones" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-recomendaciones" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-chat-left-text-fill"></i> Recomendaciones</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#nav-Incapacidad" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-Incapacidad" aria-selected="false"><i class="histonav bi-virus"></i> Incapacidad</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-ayudadx" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false" title="Ayuda Dx. Procedimientos y Drogodependencia">
      <i class="histonav bi-file-earmark-medical-fill"></i>
    </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```